# Login site using casperJS

Tags: authentication, phantomjs, casperjs, autofill

I am using casperJS to auto fill a form and test some functionality of the site.

I need to fill the input fields and click the Continue button at the bottom on thsi page

http://www.snapdeal.com/checkout?cartId=9fe651cb-6a8d-4d18-b82f-d470ecfe05fd

Fill() command of casperJS is not doing the same . How can i do ??

PS: Have tried the solutions given on other similar questions on stackoverflow but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Where is the continue button?
Which form you actually want to fill?